# Weird behavior in for solving TISE in harmonic oscillator potential using the shooting method

Tags: numerics, computational-physics, quantum-mechanics

I was solving the time independent Schrödinger equation using the shooting method for harmonic oscillator potential. This is the code that I wrote for that with the results (code is written in julia):

```matlab
m, omega, hbar, del_x = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1e-3

function get_eigenfunction(xgrid, V_x, E_n, del_x, m=1; hbar=1, s=1e5)
    psi_vals = [0, s]  # Initial Conditions
    
    for i = 2:(length(xgrid) - 1)
        psi_ii = 2psi_vals[i] * ((m * del_x^2) * (V_x[i] - E_n) / hbar^2 + 1) - psi_vals[i-1]
        append!(psi_vals, psi_ii)
    end
    
    normalize!(psi_vals)
    return psi_vals
end

E_100 = (100 + 0.5)*hbar*omega
x1 = collect(-15:del_x:15)
V_x1 = [1/2 * m * omega * x^2 for x in x1]
phi2_x1 = get_eigenfunction(x1, V_x1, E_100, del_x).^2
scaling = maximum(V_x1) / maximum(phi2_x1)
plot(x1, V_x1)
plot!(x1, scaling*phi2_x1 .+ E_100)
plot!(x1, [E_100 for x in x1])
```

[image: Plot Result 1]

Now, when I increase the range of x, to sample more value of potential then the result is quite weird as I get an insane overshoot at the right boundary point:

```matlab
E_100 = (100 + 0.5)*hbar*omega
x1 = collect(-20:del_x:20)
V_x1 = [1/2 * m * omega * x^2 for x in x1]
phi2_x1 = get_eigenfunction(x1, V_x1, E_100, del_x).^2
scaling = maximum(V_x1) / maximum(phi2_x1)
plot(x1, V_x1)
plot!(x1, scaling*phi2_x1 .+ E_100)
plot!(x1, [E_100 for x in x1])
```

[image: Plot Result 2]

Is there any way to prevent this problem?